# Getting linking error in visual c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, msvcr90.dll, .lib

I have a `visual c++` project in my work space which is totally depend on `.lib` (static library). Now i want to create a `dll` project using the existing code in visual c++ but it shows me following `linking` error:

```
Linking...
 msvcrt.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __thiscall exception::~exception(void)" (??1exception@@UAE@XZ) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
 msvcrt.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall exception::exception(char const * const &)" (??0exception@@QAE@ABQBD@Z) already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(stdexcpt.obj)
 msvcrt.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: _free already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj)
 msvcrt.lib(MSVCRT.dll) : error LNK2005: _malloc already defined in LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj)
 LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib "msvcrt.lib" conflicts with use of other libs; use   /NODEFAULTLIB:library
 Debug/finaliTest.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
 Error executing link.exe.
```

I am newbie in this `visual C++`. How should i procced?

- code for `DllMain`:

  ```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "IDT_DUKPT.h"
  unsigned char stringKSN[10];
  unsigned char m_nderivation_key[16];
  unsigned char m_ninitial_key[16];

   BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, 
                  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                  LPVOID lpReserved
               )
  {   
     return TRUE;
  }  

   void OnDecryption(){

     GetKey(stringKSN, m_nderivation_key, m_ninitial_key);   
     // Initialization of the method are written in `.lib` file.

     }
  ```

Where as the `IDT_DUKPT.H` is:

```
//IDT_DUKPT.h
#define _IDT_DUKPT_H_


// TDES Encryption
void TDES_Encryption(BYTE *Data, BYTE *Key, BYTE *InitalVector, int Length);

// TDES Decryption
void TDES(BYTE *Data, BYTE *Key, BYTE *InitalVector, int Length);

// Get the Initial Key
void GetKey(BYTE *KSN, BYTE *BDK, BYTE *InitialKey);
```

I also put the `IDT_DUKPT.lib` in my project folder and add the `.lib` link to the project setting.

My main aim is to create a `dll`, So that i can use the methods from my `java` code using `JNA`.

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're mixing objects that were compiled with different options for C run-times.  Is `IDT_DUKPT.lib` a static library (a collection of object files rather than an import library for a separate DLL)?  If it is, I'd guess one was compiled using `/MTd` while the other is using the `/MD` option.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.80).aspx for details.

There are a few ways you could fix this.  The easiest is probably to change the compiler flags for your app to use whichever of `/MDd` or `/MTd` it wasn't already using:

1. Right click on the relevant csproj in Solution Explorer and select Properties
2. In the dialog that appears, expand C/C++ then select Command Line
3. In the options box on the right of the dialog, add `/MTd` or `/MDd`
4. For completeness, change the configuration to Release and add `/MT` or `/MD` to its compiler options

Comment: Yes you are right .lib file is a static library. Would you please tell me how to change the compiler?

Comment: @AmitPal I've updated my answer with notes on this.  I'm not a big user of the visual studio IDE so there may be other, easier, routes to achieve the same result

Comment: @simoc : Actually i am on Microsoft visual c++ and you are talking about visual studio 2010

Comment: @AmitPal I don't have any other versions of msvc available to offer instructions.  If you hunt through project properties menu options you should find a comparable option under something like "compiler flags", "cflags" or "command line"

Comment: Maybe the options have been used the other way round.  Can you try changing to use the /MD option (debug, single threaded) in your app please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21386/discussion-between-simonc-and-amit-pal)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the new DLL, then add each file in the hierarchy, after each addition, compile?

Remember, when you are adding a DLL, the exporting comes into picture. You will not be able directly add like that.

Comment: Yeh i did that but it was showing me errors and when i searched for them it tell that i have already created a dynamic and now i am adding a static library. not sure

Comment: Try mentioning LIBCMTD.lib under linker->Input->  'Ignore Specific Default Libraries'

Comment: @Naresh Introducing a second C run-time is likely to increase the number of linker errors - every standard C call will end up generating a duplicate symbol error